# What happened to the UserId autofill for Data Explorer?

Tags: support, data-explorer, autocomplete

I noticed recently that when I login to data.SE, the `UserId` parameter no longer works as advertised:

> The ##UserId## parameter is treated specially for users who are logged in. If they have an account on the target site that shares the email used in their Data Explorer account, their user ID on that site will be automatically populated.

Is this by design, or a regression due to other changes?